# How do I enable multiple contexts in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

We'd like to set up a development environment using cloud foundry.  Unfortunately, our architecture packages a few different wars into one webapp, each war running under its own context.  Furthermore, we have a bunch of absolute URIs with the context in it, too many to rename all of them to relative URIs.

CF apparently deploys a war to the root context.  Is there any way to get around this?  I tried faking it by editing the web.xml in tomcat/conf/ but when I did a whole other application folder was created on my machine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you push a Java web app to CloudFoundry, the platform installs and configures the Tomcat instance(s) for you, and you have limited control over the configuration. It is possible to configure your own Tomcat (or other application container) and push it along with your application instead of letting the platform do it for you.

There is a good blog post about using this bring-your-own-container approach with Tomcat 7: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework-2/.

I suggest using this approach to configure a Tomcat 6 or 7 distribution in a way that works for your application, zip up the customized Tomcat distribution along with your war files, and push that bundle as a stand-alone app on CloudFoundry.